# SonarQube + StyleCop Plugin (for C#)

Tags: c#, sonarqube

According to http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441942
We have to set the styleCop Path as

```
  Settings > General Settings > C# > StyleCop > Path to StyleCop.dll
```

If there a way, I can set the value of

```
 sonar.stylecop.styleCopDllPath
```

using command "MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin" or any other means.

Default value is "C:/Program Files (x86)/StyleCop 4.7/StyleCop.dll"

I am using 32-bit wiindows 7, which does not have folder (Program Files (x86)).

I am using

SonarQube 4.5.6 LTS

C# Plugin version - 4.4

StyleCop version - 1.1

Thanks

Comment: So what is your question? You already know *how* to set the path. Do you expect us to check *your own PC* to find out where *you* installed StyleCop?

Comment: @nvoigt I have created a application for other teams, to run SonarQube for there dot net/vb.net application. there are more than 10 teams and using different versions of OS and visual studio as per there needs. so some of them don't have above path in there system. Is there any other way of setting stylecop path for every execution running separately.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are having problem setting the path for the styleCop.

You could try to use the environment variable %PROGRAMFILES% to get into your program files folder, regardless your operating system language.

so, it would be something like that:
%PROGRAMFILES%/StyleCop 4.7/StyleCop.dll

Just make sure you have this directory on your machine!

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have created a application for other teams, to run SonarQube for there dot net/vb.net application. there are more than 10 teams and using different versions of OS and visual studio as per there needs. so some of them don't have above path in there system. Is there any other way of setting stylecop path for every execution running separately

Comment: @atulya Perhaps this may help you then: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/25/sharing-source-analysis-settings-across-projects.aspx